# iOS How to detect only the front face?

Tags: ios, face-detection, core-image

I have been working on apple `CoreImage` library to detect faces, so far i have been successful, i am able to detect faces.

What i really want is later to send that image to server for face recognition. But for recognition face, must be front facing camera. The problem is `CoreImage` will detect face even in side position, and that is not good.

I get the metadata object

```
if([metadataObject.type isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeFace])
```

But am unable to find if the person is looking sideways. Is there easy way to this, like some property, or some class, because I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could just check for the detection of left and right eyes:

```
for (CIFaceFeature *f in features)
{
    NSLog(NSStringFromRect(f.bounds));

    if (f.hasLeftEyePosition)
        NSLog("Left eye %g %g", f.leftEyePosition.x. f.leftEyePosition.y);

    if (f.hasRightEyePosition)
        NSLog("Right eye %g %g", f.rightEyePosition.x. f.rightEyePosition.y);

    if (f.hasmouthPosition)
        NSLog("Mouth %g %g", f.mouthPosition.x. f.mouthPosition.y);
}
```

code snippet from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html)

Previously I've used OpenCV (which you can embed in iOS apps), which has [frontal face haar cascades pre-trained](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml).